# Sorting an object using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have an object array called Persons and would like to sort by one of its members, I am new to javascript prorotype and not sure how to do this. The object looks like this:

```
[ Object { EntityId=0, Name="Edibert", Number="1234", Value=""}]

[ Object { EntityId=0, Name="Jairo", Number="1234", Value=""}]
```

So it has a few more items there for that array of object Persons. I know i can access the name by doing something like `this.Persons[0].Name`. But how can i sort it by Name?.

thank you so much

Comment: You can use a small lib like this to help: https://github.com/webadvanced/jsLINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without Prototype:

```
Persons.sort(function(a,b) {
    if(a.Name < b.Name) { return -1; }
    if(a.Name > b.Name) { return 1; }
    return 0;
});
```

Use any properties of the object you want from within the `sort` function, so long as you return one of the following values:

- (-1) if a is to appear before b in the final array
- (1) if a is to appear after b
- (0) if the two items being sorted are identical

In reality, any negative or positive number would work as a return value, but `-1` and `1` are conventional.